# English term for "Standardabschätzung"

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-german

In complex path integration there is the following fundamental inequality

$$
\left\vert \int_\gamma f(z) dz \right\vert 
\leq \mathcal{L} \left( \gamma\right) \cdot \max \left\lbrace\left\vert f \left( z \right) \right\vert : z \in \gamma^*\right\rbrace
$$

where $\mathcal{L} \left( \gamma\right)$ denotes the length of $\gamma$ and $\gamma^\star$ denotes its image.

In German, this inequality is often referred to as the *Standardabschätzung*, which could literally be translated to "standard estimate". Is this a commonly used translation or is there another name in the English literature for this estimate?

Comment: What is the source of this inequalitiy?

Comment: I do not have a specific source, but any german book on the theory of functions will do. Most likely the notation will differ however

Comment: Looking in a dictionary in the Internet i found the same word in english

Comment: You mean the word "Standardabschätzung" is also used in english literature?

Comment: yes that's what i have found.

Comment: Very interesting. Would you mind to post a link?

Comment: Now i think this is better standardassessment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the "Estimation Lemma" or the "M L inequality" (for the M and the L appearing in there). See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

PS: Not to be confused with the other typical use of the abbreviation "M L" which often refers to Maximum Likelihood, and corresponding estimates.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for (allthough I'm quite surprised that I've never seen this name before)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a commonly used translation, but if you referred to it as the "standard inequality" or the "trivial inequality" people would understand and wouldn't think it was odd.